# How do I sort and filter file names in python using list comprehension?

Tags: python, list-comprehension, listdir

I am trying to sort the file names in a directory, while filter based on a keywords. It partially works. The sort part works, but as I add filter part I get following error.

```
TypeError: argument of type 'PosixPath' is not iterable
```

Working code (without filter),

```
[path for path in sorted(Path(DIR_PATH).iterdir(), key=os.path.getmtime)]
```

As I add the filter, it does not work,

```
[path for path in sorted(Path(DIR_PATH).iterdir(), key=os.path.getmtime) if "search words" in path]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Side-note: You may not want to use `Path` objects for the initial sort, especially if this code will run on Windows. `os.scandir`, while lower level, exposes the entries in the directory with some elements of the `stat` for free (all of them on Windows) and the rest cached on first access (so if you check multiple values, you still only `stat` once). `sorted((entry for entry in os.scandir(DIR_PATH) if "search words" in entry.path), key=lambda e: e.stat().st_mtime))` (deferring the sort until after the filtering to minimize the items sorted).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should convert the `Path` object to a string before you can use the `in` operator to test for a substring:

```
[
    path
    for path in sorted(Path(DIR_PATH).iterdir(), key=os.path.getmtime)
    if "search words" in str(path)
]
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked. However, I am still wondering that why the error said, <TypeError: argument of type 'PosixPath' is not iterable>. The search part was not a part of iteration.